# How to put two different model's uuid and id in a same url?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have two different model linked by a `ForeignKey` one contains a certain `uuid` and the other has a certain `id`. I'd like to be able to put these in the same URL.

Here's the **models.py** :

```
class Creation(models.Model):
    ...
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    creation = models.ForeignKey(Creation, null=True)
```

Here's what the **URL** pattern should look like :

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
```

**Views.py**

```
def edit(request, id, uuid):
    user_uuid = User.objects.filter(id=id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id, uuid=user_uuid.creation.uuid)
```

As you can see the view function doesn't make any sense since I don't see how what I'm trying to do should work but the `User` should be the id in the URL and the `Creation` should be the uuid since each user can have many `Creation`s.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `models.ForeignKey(UserCreation, null=True)` in here, Is it `Creation` or `UserCreation`?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Edited the typo

Comment: what is `UserInfo`? If its a model then please post it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I renamed Userinfo to User and Usercreation to Creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but I *think* what you want is:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=id)
creation = user.creation_set.filter(uuid=uuid)
```

Note of course though that since uuid is unique, there's no need to use the User ID in the query at all; you could drop it from the URL altogether, use just the uuid to get the Creation, then get the user via `creation.user`.

Comment: I'll simplify the uuid later on so it contains 8 characters, but I wanted to have /user_id/creation_uuid so the user can see his id while being on a different creation, what does creation_set do ?

Comment: Gives you all the Creations associated with that particular user. See "reverse relations" in the docs.